# New column to flag as top X based on another column for multiple products over a time series in python

Tags: python, pandas

Question is long winded so I'll explain.

I have a dataframe which looks like this in python:

```
Date        Product        Score       Score_pct
01/01/2021  A              15          0.015
02/01/2021  A              18          0.025
01/01/2021  B              5           0.05
02/01/2021  B              9           0.04
01/01/2021  C              8           0.10
02/01/2021  C              19          0.055
```

I have data going back 5 years for each of my products (6 products) and my dataframe is ordered in the fashion as shown above. There is one entry per product per date as above.

I would like a new column to flag if the 'Score_pct' is in the top 10 over the history for that product. If it is then I would like it to return the corresponding value in the 'Score' column.

Lets say for product A the first two are in the top 10 and the last value for C is also in the top 10. The desired result would be this. Note that the ranking is within that product group.

```
Date        Product        Score       Score_pct      Flag
01/01/2021  A              15          0.015          15
02/01/2021  A              18          0.025          18
01/01/2021  B              5           0.05           NaN
02/01/2021  B              9           0.04           NaN
01/01/2021  C              8           0.10           NaN
02/01/2021  C              19          0.055          19
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: By _"for product A the first two are in the top 10"_ do you mean the A rows are in the top ten **of A**, or the top ten **overall**?

Comment: Yes in the top 10 of only the A time series not overall. Same for C. (Poor example on ‘C’ as 0.1 is larger than 0.05 and not in top 10 in example but I think you see what I mean)

Comment: @AM12 please, let us know if my answer below is what you needed. If so, accept the answer, please. Hope it has helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following is what you need.

**(1)** Let's create a longer example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", "04/01/2021", "01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", "04/01/2021", "01/01/2021", "02/01/2021", "03/01/2021", "04/01/2021"],
                   "Product":["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"],
                   "Score":[15, 18, 12, 10, 5, 9, 7, 3, 8, 19, 3, 9],  
                   "Score_pct": [0.015, 0.025, 0.02, 0.3, 0.05, 0.04, 0.02, 0.3, 0.10, 0.45, 0.02, 0.3]})
```

This gives us the DataFrame below.

```
Date    Product Score   Score_pct
0   01/01/2021  A   15  0.015
1   02/01/2021  A   18  0.025
2   03/01/2021  A   12  0.020
3   04/01/2021  A   10  0.300
4   01/01/2021  B   5   0.050
5   02/01/2021  B   9   0.040
6   03/01/2021  B   7   0.020
7   04/01/2021  B   3   0.300
8   01/01/2021  C   8   0.100
9   02/01/2021  C   19  0.450
10  03/01/2021  C   3   0.020
11  04/01/2021  C   9   0.300
```

**(2)** Then we can create a ranking for the products. Here I made a top 2 ranking, but in your case you have to define `top = 10`:

```
top = 2

ranking = df.groupby(['Product'])[['Score_pct']].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(top, columns=['Score_pct'])).reset_index()[['Product','Score_pct']].sort_values(by=['Product','Score_pct'], ascending=[True, False])
```

In my `top = 2` example the result is

```
Product Score_pct
0   A   0.300
1   A   0.025
2   B   0.300
3   B   0.050
4   C   0.450
5   C   0.300
```

**(3)** Bring the ranking into our original DataFrame:

```
df = df.merge(ranking, how="left", on=['Product', 'Score_pct'], indicator=True)
```

Leading us to

```
Date    Product Score   Score_pct   _merge
0   01/01/2021  A   15  0.015   left_only
1   02/01/2021  A   18  0.025   both
2   03/01/2021  A   12  0.020   left_only
3   04/01/2021  A   10  0.300   both
4   01/01/2021  B   5   0.050   both
5   02/01/2021  B   9   0.040   left_only
6   03/01/2021  B   7   0.020   left_only
7   04/01/2021  B   3   0.300   both
8   01/01/2021  C   8   0.100   left_only
9   02/01/2021  C   19  0.450   both
10  03/01/2021  C   3   0.020   left_only
11  04/01/2021  C   9   0.300   both
```

**(4)** Lastly, create the 'Flag' column with NaNs and then add the respective scores:

```
import numpy as np

df['Flag'] = np.NaN

df.loc[df['_merge']=="both", ['Flag']] = df[df['_merge']=="both"]['Score']

df.drop(['_merge'], axis=1, inplace=True) # optional
```

We end up with the following DataFrame:

```
Date    Product Score   Score_pct   Flag
0   01/01/2021  A   15  0.015   NaN
1   02/01/2021  A   18  0.025   18.0
2   03/01/2021  A   12  0.020   NaN
3   04/01/2021  A   10  0.300   10.0
4   01/01/2021  B   5   0.050   5.0
5   02/01/2021  B   9   0.040   NaN
6   03/01/2021  B   7   0.020   NaN
7   04/01/2021  B   3   0.300   3.0
8   01/01/2021  C   8   0.100   NaN
9   02/01/2021  C   19  0.450   19.0
10  03/01/2021  C   3   0.020   NaN
11  04/01/2021  C   9   0.300   9.0
```